# I cannot see HTML5 EventSource event with onmessage method in Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, html

I tried to use the `EventSource` object with a little example

On the client side, I have this page with the following script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Welcome!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var sse = new EventSource('event-source.php');
        
        sse.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log(event.data);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
        }

        sse.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        }
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script calls event-source.php on server. Here is event-source.php :

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/event-stream');
echo 'data: '.time().PHP_EOL;
```

When I try this configuration on Firefox, the method "onMessage" is well called, but not with Chrome. When I put the "onError" method, it seems that it is called but I cannot see the error cause.

What should I do?

Comment: Tried it in chrome version 22, it worked.

Comment: Not on my system, I run on Ubuntu 12.04, I tried with Ubuntu 12.04, Chromium 20 and Chrome 22.
In addition, onmessage et onerror are called both on Firefox , but Event data are correctly displayed...

Comment: works fine on Chrome 32.0.1700.102 m

Comment: Your PHP code is sending back data without the `message ` envelope as it were but is not maintaining an open connection - it is re-establishing the connection every seconds

Comment: Maybe not related, but when the connection is over HTTP there is a limit to the number of connections you can make: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852690/sseeventsource-why-no-more-than-6-connections Therefore it is a good idea to close the connection, e.g. onbeforeunload call sse.close()

Answer (score 1):

CLIENT

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
var source = new EventSource("/html/demo_sse.php");
source.onopen = function() {
document.getElementById("myH1").innerHTML = "Getting server updates";
};
source.onmessage = function(event) {
document.getElementById("myDIV").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};        
} else {
document.getElementById("myDIV").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>
```

SERVER

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    $time = date('r');
    echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
    flush();
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

In `onmessage` you are calling wanted object property, why dont you do the same in `onerror`?

I think that your `onerror` should look like this:

```
   sse.onerror = function(event) {
      console.log(event.message);
   }
```

**Explanation:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events
 - this link says "When problems occur (...), an **error event** is generated. "

So when custom error handling you should learn about the **ErrorEvent** structure :) It goes like this:

1. **ErrorEvent.*message*** (Read only) Is a DOMString containing a
   human-readable error message describing the problem.
2. **ErrorEvent.*filename*** (Read only) Is a DOMString containing the name
   of the script file in which the error occurred.
3. **ErrorEvent.*lineno*** (Read only) Is an integer containing the line
   number of the script file on which the error occurred.
4. **ErrorEvent.*column*** (Read only) Is an integer containing the column
   number of the script file on which the error occurred.
5. **ErrorEvent.*error*** (Read only)   Is a JavaScript Object that is
   concerned by the event.

More info and source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent

Answer (score -1):

This topic is way too old. But even today, I have sometimes seen mixed behaviours when using `onmessage` with the EventSource.

So far, I have had much success with the following variant

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Welcome!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var sse = new EventSource('event-source.php');

        sse.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            console.log(event.data);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
        });

        
        sse.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
            console.log(event);
        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```