# Spring WebFlux SSE + angular - detect open connection

Tags: angular, spring-webflux, eventsource

I created a Server-Sent Event connection with Spring and Angular to send a periodic message about possible incoming restart.

But the SSE connection is limited to 6 connections per user. This means that if I open more than 6 tabs, everything slows down because the browser can't get connections - the page doesn't load.

angular

```
const source = new EventSource('/api/incoming-restart-event')
source.addEventListener('message', (message: MessageEvent) => {
  minutesUntilRestart = message.data
})
```

Spring

```
@GetMapping(path = "/incoming-restart-event", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Date> incomingRestartEventStream() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(3), Duration.ofSeconds(100))
            .map(sequence -> incomingRestartService.getIncomingRestartTime() != null
                    ? incomingRestartService.getIncomingRestartTime()
                    : new Date(0));
}
```

What would be the best way to only send updates to the active tab (or just last active tab)? Basically - I want to make sure that we aren't opening 6+ open connections.

I would prefer to handle this in the back-end so I don't have to build some kind of a front-end session handler for trying to count user's active tabs.

Comment: `But the SSE connection is limited to 6 connections per user` why, as this makes no sense.

Comment: I agree. But that's just how it is. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852690/sseeventsource-why-no-more-than-6-connections

Comment: whats the user case, keeping track of 1000 clients active tabs is going to be a pain. I would find another way, good luck.

Comment: I just want to make sure that the website keeps working when the user opens more than 6 tabs.

If needed and it's possible, I would be okay with a front-end solution as well - so each user's browser doesn't open new connections with each tab.

Comment: This feels more like you want to implement something that doesnt seem like a problem yet. But good luck.

Comment: It actually is a problem - I have a tool that people use with multiple tabs to multitask and work with different datasets which are relevant to each other.

Comment: 6 connection is only applicable if you are not using HTTP/2. Recent version of Spring supports HTTP/2 so I would recommend to upgrade your stack.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upgrade to to HTTP/2 as of this moment. I guess my only solution is to make it a regular REST end-point to query state and create a front-end poller which shoots the query on a timer.

Comment: @PadaKatel did you actually find a way to get number of connections ? From the debugger i can get info like `((FluxRefCount) events).connection` and check that against null, but its functions not allowed inside the code

Comment: No, I unfortunately never checked the number of active connections. The 6 connection limit was true and so I couldn't use webflux for this feature.